# $DISPLAY env not set using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding

I'm using ssh from my Mac terminal to login to a server at my university. I'm trying to launch cscope which uses X and get "Error initializing application (Tcl_AppInit?): no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable". This is expected. I've tried adding the -X parameter when logging in but that doesn't work. I know this can work with putty and x-term but that's only with Windows machines. Is there any way to launch a gui just from my terminal through playing with $DISPLAY and X tunneling? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you ask a question it's recommended that you try to do some research on your own. A little searching can go a long way.

Anyways

- [how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-with-ssh-on-mac-os-x-leopard](http://dyhr.com/2009/09/05/how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-with-ssh-on-mac-os-x-leopard/)
- [MIT article on the subject](http://www.mit.edu/people/lucylim/MacX11.html)
- [my Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mac+ssh+X11)

If you can't get it working, I suggest looking at the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) Q&A forums. 
Super User is similar to Stack Overflow but it's more geared towards arcane terminal stuff and general computer questions whereas Stack Overflow is more geared towards programming specifically. You might be able to find more knowledgeable people there.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the SU forum reference. That should be helpful in the future. Also, I assure you that I do research before posting. Nevertheless I solved this problem by simply using X11.app included in OSX (DOH!). The only reason this was hard to find was because Apple replaced X11 with XQuartz. Upon installation the forwarding is working perfectly. Thanks!